# NativeScript when adding custom resource/json files

Tags: nativescript

I am creating a project to target Android and in it, I want it to come with a .json file from which some data will be loaded.

I put my .json file into the Android folder. When running "**tns run android --device 1**" (which is my physical device) I get:

```
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
 [echo] Handling aidl files...
 [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Handling Resources...
 [aapt] Found new input file
 [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: /Users/konrad/Desktop/NativeScript/hello-world/platforms/android/res res
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: /Users/konrad/Desktop/NativeScript/hello-world/platforms/android/res small.json

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/ant/build.xml:694: null returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds
Command ant failed with exit code 1
```

The file is called **small.json**

EDIT: Even if I remove the file, the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

The property of Android is that it restricts access to some parts of the file system. There are two ways of accessing files on NativeScript for Android:

1) JavaScript way

```
var fs = require('file-system');
var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
var myFile = documents.getFile(filename);
```

as specified in the docs: https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/blob/master/ApiReference/file-system/HOW-TO.md

2) Android specific way including a third party library called "json-simple" which needs to be attached using the command **tns library add android** .

```
var context = app.android.context;
var assets = context.getAssets();

var br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(assets.open(filename)));

var parser = new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser();
try {
    parser.parse(br);
} catch (ex) {
    var javaEx = ex.nativeException;
    var msg = javaEx.getMessage();
    console.log("whops! : "+msg);

}
```